# It will be nice to share the answers we like on social networks

Tags: feature-request, answers, social-networking, sharing, share-this

I came thro a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8721/15219) and i found an interesting answer to it. The answer is obviously the highest voted answer to the question but it was not accepted by the user who asked the question. I felt that the answer by [Pierre 303](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/2567/pierre-303) must be honored by sharing it on social networks. It would be nice to share an answer on social network by highlighting the answer.

Answer (score 7):

We already have such a feature!

Simply click on the "link" hyperlink:

[image: clicking on the "link" hyperlink below the question]

And you get a link to the question that you can copy and paste into whatever social network you fancy:

[image: "share a link to this answer" pop-up, containing a selectable link to the question]

This a "permalink" directly to the answer, so you don't have to worry that the person you share the link with will be unable to find exactly what you want them to see.

---

Beyond that, of course, we want you to share the *question* on social networking sites, rather than a specific answer. *All* of the answers are likely to be very good, and the person with whom you share the question might very well want to post one of their own! Linking directly to an answer might discourage that. To share a link to the question itself, use one of these handy icons:

[image: Facebook and Twitter icons to the left of the question]